# Understanding std::thread constructor call with member function that takes parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread, c2664

I'm trying to code a simple client-server-application with winSock to better understand how it all works. The server should be able to support multiple clients and therefore starts a new thread for receiving client messages each time a new client connects to the server.

I have a struct that stores information about the connected client like the winSock `SOCKET` so I don't have to worry about calling winSock's `closesocket(...)` function as it will be called in the destructor of my `ConnectedClient` struct:

```
struct ConnectedClient
{
    SOCKET sock;
    bool disconnected;
    
    ConnectedClient(SOCKET&& sock)
        : sock(std::move(sock)), disconnected(false)
    {}
}
```

In the server class I have a `std::vector` which holds all connected clients and to add a newly connected client I call my function `AddClient`. In this function I start a thread that runs the function `ClientRcv`:

```
class Server
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ConnectedClient>> clients;
    
    void ClientRcv(const std::unique_ptr<ConnectedClient>& c)
    {
        //...
        c->disconnected = true;
    }
    
    void AddClient(SOCKET&& clientSocket)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<ConnectedClient> cc(std::make_unique<ConnectedClient>(std::move(clientSocket)));
        clients.push_back(std::move(cc));
        
        //(1) this works
        std::thread rcvThread([this]() { ClientRcv(clients.back()); });
        
        //(2) this doesn't
        //std::thread rcvThread(&Server::ClientRcv, this, clients.back());
        
        rcvThread.detach();
    }
}
```

Now my question is this:
When calling the constructor of `std::thread`, why does (1) compile and (2) throw following compiler error

```
Error   C2664   'std::tuple<void (__cdecl Server::* )(const std::unique_ptr<Server::ConnectedClient,std::default_delete<Server::ConnectedClient>> &),Server *,std::unique_ptr<Server::ConnectedClient,std::default_delete<Server::ConnectedClient>>>::tuple(std::tuple<void (__cdecl Server::* )(const std::unique_ptr<Server::ConnectedClient,std::default_delete<Server::ConnectedClient>> &),Server *,std::unique_ptr<Server::ConnectedClient,std::default_delete<Server::ConnectedClient>>> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'std::allocator_arg_t'
```

Comment: What is `ClientRcvThread`? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. And is the error message you show the *only* output when you build? If not, then copy-paste the full and complete output into the question.

Comment: At a guess, you need `std::reference_wrapper(clients.back())` - `std::thread` copies its arguments. (That's for compilation; the `detach` and the use of references to `unique_ptr`s stored in vectors emit a very strong aura of lifetime-management problems, and you might want to think some more.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thx for the hint on my spelling of ClientRcv. Yes it is the only error message (It is the only item in visual studio's Error List with the error tag).

Comment: Then the problem is as mentioned by @molbdnilo. See [`std::cref` (and `std::ref`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) for a simple way to handle functions taking references as arguments.